# Add element to empty array

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In plpgSql, I need to add number to empty numeric array, this empty numeric array is variable.

What I do is this:

```
DECLARE
    new_arr INTEGER[];
BEGIN
    SELECT array_append(new_arr, 4) INTO new_arr;
```

This works, but I am not sure, may be exists better way  for this?

Comment: `new_arr := new_arr || 4` is probably faster: http://adpgtech.blogspot.de/2014/11/assignment-beats-select-into.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: no, it is equal - in this case. look to plpgsql source code. Andrew's measuring is correct, but investigation is wrong, and comments are out too. What is important - how much columns are in result - when one, then plpgsql call executor directly, when more, then SPI is used (it is slower).

Comment: @PavelStehule: but the assignment is still faster than the `select`. Plus I personally find `:=` more consistent within a procedural language than using a `select` to assign a value.

Comment: I agree, so `:=` should be used there. But any assignment produce SELECT .. hidden, but SELECT. a := 1 and SELEC1 1 INTO a are same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it, but this style is little bit obscure

use a assign statement, but you don't need a forget a correct initialization. In your example a new_arr doesn't hold a empty array. It holds a NULL. Do:

```
DECLARE new_arr int[] DEFAULT '{}';
BEGIN
  new_arr := new_arr || 4;
  -- or
  new_arr := array_append(new_arr, 4);

  -- both are equal
```

`SELECT INTO` should be used if you do query to some relation.

Comment: Something does not seem correct with this answer.  In 9.5.1, `RAISE NOTICE 'Array % has length of %', new_arr, array_length(new_arr, 1);` prints `Array {} has length of <NULL>`.  So does it really create an empty array, does it just rely on some other obscure reason to work, or  is it a bug in array_length()?

Comment: In addition prior to any assignment `ASSERT new_arr IS NULL;` asserts which means that it is not null in spite of what array_length() thinks.

Comment: @Neil - probably you forgot initialize a array to '{}'.

Comment: Nope, here is the test case `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_empty_array_length()
RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
 new_arr integer[] DEFAULT '{}';
BEGIN
 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755195/add-element-to-empty-array
 RAISE NOTICE 'Array % has length %', new_arr, array_length(new_arr, 1);
 return array_length(new_arr, 1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
`

Comment: You and Tom had some discussions about this a couple of years ago, which is why I did not raise a bug report yet.  Hopefully it is something I don't understand.

Comment: @Neil: This is little bit offtopic - I remember little bit some discussion - the empty array has undefined dimensions in Postgres, so array_length(a, dimension) is undef too, and a equivalent of undef is NULL.  It is valid from theoretical view, but it is not too much practical from pragmatic view http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAEZATCWKyM0qpi+kimKr1s5MNaoT07j_t6Qe7VNWEx8k=AQfqA@mail.gmail.com. We introduced new function `cardinality` that returns 0 for empty array.